PIL module not installed
I'm using a Windows laptop. I've installed Pillow. But when I try to Import an image from PIL, the error message comes up: "PIL module is not installed." How shall I resolve this issue?
from PIL import Image

img = image.open(with directory path)

then i want to check different things 

print(img), (img.format)


How did you install pillow? How do you run the program? Could you print the version and location of python interpreter? (from code: you may find you are running not the expected interpreter, but a different one: very frequent problem)

I used powershell copy code pip3 install pillow.  Then I got confirmation that it has been installed.

Pillow in C: my directory \appdata\roaming\python\python 312\site-packages (10.3.0)

python -m pip install pillow

We use conda because it provides us virtual environment. Maybe you just installed in a virtual environment. Or you installed python differently and then you installed conda, so you may get two different pythons (and what it is first in PATH take precedence)

Thank you for pointing that I was wondering why I'm getting two python 3 in Subline Text. Is deleteing everything and reinstalling will resolve this issue?
